Is launchd confined by SIP or AMFI?
Given that signature checks for kernel extensions and executables are both carried out in userspace, this tells me that SIP and the sandbox aren't running when launchd is still the only process running. But, I can't be sure, so I ask: is launche completely unconfined by the security features that were introduced by SIP (e.g., Sandbox, AMFI, entitlements, SIP, etc.)?

launchd is tightly integrated with Sandbox, entitlements etc.
I did some research on this and came upon this very interesting article from The Eclectic Light Company; AMFI: checking file integrity on your Mac
Contrary to your assertion, launchd isn’t the only process running.  It actually tightly integrated sandboxd, AMFI, trustd.  See the following excerpts from the article:

It normally starts after loginwindow and sandboxd (a relative), and before syspolicyd and trustd (on which it relies).


AMFI checks in with launchd, and as well as checking signatures and their certificates, it checks entitlements and provisioning profiles, producing a filtered entitlement dictionary for an app.


I've already read that article. It doesn't answer my question. You are also incorrect about launchd not being alone because those other services get started by it.
